# KeyError during template rendering

Tags: django

I am facing KeyError while populating table using django tables2. 
i have not use django model and directly using django row query.

Error during template rendering

In template C:\Users\Shariq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django_tables2\templates\django_tables2\table.html, error at line 11

```
state_name
1   {% load django_tables2 %}
2   {% load i18n %}
3   
4   <div class="table-container">
5   {% block table %}
6   <table{% if table.attrs %} {{ table.attrs.as_html }}{% endif %}>
7       {% block table.thead %}
8       {% if table.show_header %}
9       <thead>
10          <tr>
11          {% for column in table.columns %}
12              {% if column.orderable %}
13              <th {{ column.attrs.th.as_html }}><a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_order_by_field=column.order_by_alias.next %}">{{ column.header }}</a></th>
14              {% else %}
15              <th {{ column.attrs.th.as_html }}>{{ column.header }}</th>
16              {% endif %}
17          {% endfor %}
18          </tr>
19      </thead>
20      {% endif %}
```

views.py

```
def people(request): 
    cursor = connection.cursor() 
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM country_details") 
    Result_List = cursor.fetchall() 
    list = country_detailstable(Result_List) 
    RequestConfig(request).configure(list) 
    return render(request, "tables_dynamic.html", {'row': list})
```

Comment: can you paste your views for this

Comment: def people(request):
        # queryset=country_details.get.object.all()
        #Country_details1 = country_details(Result_List)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM country_details")
        Result_List = cursor.fetchall()   
        list = country_detailstable(Result_List)
        RequestConfig(request).configure(list)

        return render(request, "tables_dynamic.html", {'row': list})

Comment: ^ Its not readable. Try to edit in your question with proper indentation

Comment: i am fetching records using row sql query and after rendering it shows null records

Comment: def people(request):
 cursor = connection.cursor()
 cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM country_details")
 Result_List = cursor.fetchall()
 list = country_detailstable(Result_List)
 RequestConfig(request).configure(list)
return render(request, "tables_dynamic.html", {'row': list})

Comment: def people(request):     cursor = connection.cursor() 
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM country_details")     Result_List = cursor.fetchall()     list = country_detailstable(Result_List) 
    RequestConfig(request).configure(list)     return render(request, "tables_dynamic.html", {'row': list})